# Any way to determine size of iCloud key value storage to ensure it's < 1MB?

Tags: ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Is there a way to determine how much of the 1MB allotted an app is using for iCloud KVS? i checked the settings>iCloud route, but I don't think if it's KVS it shows up there. I'm just storing an array of some strings, but just wanted to see what else I might be able to sync that would help the user. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is possible to estimate allocated space by looking at this file:

```
du -h /Users/<user>/Library/Containers/<app-bundle-name>/Data/Library/SyncedPreferences/<app-bundle-name>plist
```